# Laravel Feature Tests: Mock Request URI

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-testing

So in my application I've some routes that need special treatment which is why I have something like this:

```
Route::prefix('external')->group(function () {
    Route::any(Request::path(), 'ExternalController@handle');
});
```

Basically every route which is `/api/external*` goes into that part.

Somehow, **when I run my feature tests**, `Request::path()` or `request()->path()` (doesn't matter) is always `/`

I also tried `$_SERVER` but this isnt even defined at this point.

My Test looks something like this:

```
public function testExternal()
{
    $response = $this
        ->put($this->externalUrl . '/' . $some['id'], [
            'data' => []
        ]);
    
    // ...
}
```

So I've read some articles here on stackoverflow and what I already tried was this:

```
    $response = $this
        ->withServerVariables(['REQUEST_URI' => $this->externalUrl . '/' . $some['id']])
        ->put($this->externalUrl . '/' . $some['id'], [
            'data' => []
        ]);
```

and also this:

```
    Request::shouldReceive('path')
        ->once()
        ->andReturn($this->externalUrl . '/' . $some['id']);
```

but this doesn't work at all, I just get errors like this:

> Received Mockery_2_Illuminate_Http_Request::setUserResolver(), but no expectations were specified

And even tho I try to set an expectation for this, it just doesn't work.

So what I'm looking for is to either Mock `$_SERVER` or `Request::path` or to somehow figure out, why `Request::path` is always just `/`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, you have to use the first thing you showed us, `put`, you do not have to mock anything, BUT what is `externalUrl` ? What is its value ?

Comment: It's ``/api/external/lookup/1``

So basically the right path

Comment: It's funny, if I use this:

    ``Route::any('external/lookup/{id}', function () {
        dd(request()->server('REQUEST_URI'));
    });``

this works

Comment: Can you look at the documentation as I am on a phone trying to help you ? On the routing documentation there is a way of doing what you want without using `Request::path()` but instead something about a `match` method, that would do it for you.

Comment: In general mocking static functions is a pain and i'm not even sure what you are trying to test? create your routes and create feature tests for those.